# How to test the Mutation Observer using jest and testing library dom

Tags: jestjs, mutation-observers, testing-library

I have a function that uses the Mutation Observer to add a parameter to the href attribute in DOM links. I want to test this function and see the changes made in the DOM.

Implementation:

```js
function add(params) {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        const newLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        newLinks.forEach(function (link) {
            const url = addParams(link.href, params);
            link.setAttribute('href', url);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}
```

Test:

```js
it('test', async () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<div><a href="https://google.com">google</a></div>`;
    add({id: '123'});
    const link = getByText(document, 'google');
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(link.href).toBe(
        'https://google.com/?id=123',
      );
    });
  });
```

in the test environment the href attribute of the link element does not update, however in the browser environment it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Create and start the mutation observer first, then add the DOM element to the DOM tree.

E.g.

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { getByText, waitFor } from '@testing-library/dom';

function add(url) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                const newLinks = document.body.querySelectorAll('a');
                newLinks.forEach(function (link) {
                    link.setAttribute('href', url);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}

test('should pass', async () => {
    add('https://google.com?id=123');
    document.body.innerHTML = `<div><a href="https://google.com">google</a></div>`;
    await waitFor(() => {
        const link = (getByText(document.body, 'google') as unknown) as HTMLLinkElement;
        console.log(link.href);
        expect(link).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://google.com?id=123');
    });
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/76486218/index.test.ts
  ✓ should pass (26 ms)

  console.log
    https://google.com/

      at stackoverflow/76486218/index.test.ts:24:11

  console.log
    https://google.com/?id=123

      at stackoverflow/76486218/index.test.ts:24:11
    

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.085 s, estimated 9 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: it didn't work and I'm on the same package versions as you. Still <a> do not update, they continue without the parameters passed. I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but in your example you pass the entire URL, but that's not what I need. I take the existing link elements and pass parameters to them, I don't know what the href is, I just know what the parameters are and I hope that passing the parameters the href updates by adding, ex: https://google.com/ to https ://google.com/?id=123
Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong? In the browser it works as expected.